# Why was this answer deleted

Tags: support, specific-question

The [answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/65288/40804) given was an answer to the question, but deleted without an apparent reason.

It was an example of a thing that could be stated as true, when the question asked if there was anything that could be stated as true.

I realise my answer might not be up to the standards of the site, but simply deleting without an explanation seems neither friendly or welcoming.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I have to apologize. Usually, my personal policy is leaving flagged posts by new users open for one day after leaving a comment why it may be deleted. The post showed in the moderator queue due to not an answer and low quality flags. Therefore, I simply used the standard moderation action available directly in the queue which is following the course proposed by the flags: deletion.

This premature action was due to a very small person causing severe sleep deprevation. And it should not happen.

That being said, the answer indeed did not meet the standards as it stood. Yes, the general thought may be considered relevant, but the post lacks contextualisation and should clearly state how it answers the question. Ideally, references would be added. I hope that this post reaches you and makes you reconsider the participation in this community.

Answer (score 0):

Your post appeared in the Low Quality Posts review queue yesterday. Although I voted "Looks OK" others voted "Recommend Deletion". I think now those others were right.

I almost recommended deletion myself because the answer was very short and it did not clarify what you were trying to say. That's why I left a comment: to try to clarify it.

I would recommend supporting your future answers with relevant references and perhaps quotes from those references. Then write a few paragraphs (not just a few words) stating why those references are worth the readers' consideration.

Anyone with 15 reputation can [flag posts](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). This can be done for many reasons. I often flag answers myself as not really answers or low quality. I imagine your post was flagged for being low quality and this put it in the review queue for other uses (such as myself) to vote on whether to keep it or not. One goal in writing an answer is to make sure it is strong enough not to land in a review queue.

Comment: it was deleted by a single moderator.

Comment: I was surprised there has been no mention of Descartes classic "what can be known" on a question asking what can be known but perhaps such things are passe.
Regardless, this moderator's actions have deterred me from engaging further with this stack.